# querying a database with an arraylist

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I want to query a database using an arraylist value.
It should return a value from the database the same as one of my arraylist element if it exists.
I am trying something like this, but it is not working

```
ArrayList<String>  list  =  new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("boy");
list.add("girl");
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("url", "root", "");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select * from table where keyword= (list)");
```

Comment: For multiple values in the where clause see: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp. In your case "select * from table where keyword in ('boy', 'girl');"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
  ArrayList<String>  list  =  new ArrayList<String>();
  list.add("boy");
  list.add("girl");
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("url", "root", "");
  Statement st = con.createStatement();
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Select * from table where keyword IN (");
  boolean added = false;
  for(String s:list){
    if (added){
      sb.append(",");
    }      
    sb.append("'");
    sb.append(s);
    sb.append("'");
    added = true;
  }
  sb.append(")");
  ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using the `in` key word.

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE keyword in (";

for(String s : list)
{
    query += "'" + list + "',";
}

query += ")";
```

**SQL Injection**

*You should probably escape the list entry in order to be save against SQL injection attacks. –*

Comment: You should probably escape the list entry in order to be save against SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the query you are forming is not correct. You should be using **IN** clause, something like:

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select * from table where keyword IN (*comma-separated-value-from-list*)");
```

The only thing that is more required is converting the list into comma-separated-values, you can do something like:

```
String[] val = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
StringBuilder csvStr = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0;i<val.length;i++){
    if (val.length > 1 && i !=0) {
        csvStr.append(",");
    }
    csvStr.append ("'").append(val[i]).append("'");
}
System.out.println(csvStr);
```

And use this csvStr in the query instead:

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select * from table where keyword IN ("+csvStr.toString()+")");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `PreparedStatement` to avoid all escaping of the SQL and security issues with that.

To do that, you build a string with question marks as a placeholder, and then add the parameters to the `PreparedStatement` instead of the string;

```
String statement = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE keyword " + getIn(list.size());
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(statement);
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
    preparedStatement.setString(i+1, list.get(i));
ResultSet result = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

...where getIn is a function returning the `IN` part with question marks that is suitable for a  `PreparedStatement`;

```
static String getIn(int numParams) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("IN (?");
    for(int i=1; i<numParams; i++)
        builder.append(",?");
    builder.append(")");
    return builder.toString();
}
```